# Vue Error: "the template root requires exactly one element"

Tags: html, vue.js

I have the following components

**component**

```
<template>
<!--<post-form/>-->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <b-table :data="posts">
            <template slot-scope="props">
                <b-table-column field="completed" label="complete">
                    <b-checkbox 
                      v-model="props.row.done">
                    </b-checkbox>
                </b-table-column>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have a b-table with buefy. And I want to import the `<post-form />` component from the current component.

However, when I insert the component in the desired location, an error occurs.

`<div class="wrapping">` If I place a component under it, my table is broken.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only have one root element in the template. So, if you want to use  as a sibling of `div` with class wrapper, you need to wrap both of these to a parent div, as below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <post-form/>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <b-table :data="posts">
            <template slot-scope="props">
                <b-table-column field="completed" label="complete">
                    <b-checkbox 
                      v-model="props.row.done">
                    </b-checkbox>
                </b-table-column>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I followed your code, but I still get the table broken after <post-form />.

Comment: Ah! I delete my post-form's style-scope and it works fine.

Why does my style-scope affect parent components?

Comment: how were you applying the style scoped? Check out link here for more details on it.
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you are using Vue3, while you eslint config is still vue 2.

Try to edit your `.eslintrc.json` or something like this:

```
{
  // ...
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:vue/vue3-essential"],
  // ...
}
```

Check out reference here: [eslint-plugin-vue/#usage](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#usage)

Comment: This is for someone new to Vue3, Vue3 is now available since 2020

Comment: you are the real mvp

Comment: @Sheldon I actually had to do this with a brand new Vue 3 project created via the Vue 3 CLI

Comment: me too! thanks!!